# Wrong results with CAML Query

Tags: c#, sharepoint, expression, caml

I have a problem in generating an expression that will check if it contains a given text with accents or not.

But when I realize the search he returns only items with accents and ignore the items without accent, I would like him to return the two results together.

He seeks in three fields: "Title", "SINPCSobreProduto" and "SINPCCaracteristicas"

I use the library [Camlex](https://camlex.codeplex.com)

code:

```
var searchConditions = new List<Expression<Func<ListItem, bool>>>();
var searches= new[] {"Código", "Codigo"};
foreach (string search in searches)
{
  searchConditions.Add(x => ((string)x["Title"]).Contains(search));
  searchConditions.Add(x => ((string)x["SINPCSobreProduto"]).Contains(search));
  searchConditions.Add(x => ((string)x["SINPCCaracteristicas"]).Contains(search));
}
var searchExpr = ExpressionsHelper.CombineOr(searchConditions);
expressions.Add(searchExpr);

//here he is returning 196 items and not the 201 items because it is ignoring the 5 items
//that are without the accent.
var camlQuery = Camlex.Query().WhereAll(expressions).ToCamlQuery();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you should use WhereAny() instead of WhereAll() in the last call:

```
var camlQuery = Camlex.Query().WhereAny(expressions).ToCamlQuery();
```

I think also that it would be more clear if you would mention in your post that you use [Camlex](http://camlex.codeplex.com) library for creating dynamic query.

Comment: Hello @alex, using WhereAny () my result rose to 446 and looks like work. But there's another problem, I need to perform a function on each FieldRef to remove the accent and compare. Would have any way to run a function as it does this search?

Comment: This is my function:
private string RemoveAccents(string txt)
{
    string withAccents = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûùÇç";
    string withoutAccents = "AAAAAAaaaaaEEEEeeeeIIIIiiiiOOOOOoooooUUUuuuuCc";

    for (int i = 0; i < withAccents.Length; i++)
    {
        txt= txt.Replace(withAccents[i].ToString(), withoutAccents [i].ToString());
    }

    return txt;
}

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible because CAML is not accent insensitive. I.e. you have to build CAML query with both accent and accentless variants of the strings (like you did above) and then run your function on returned rows.